# ERLANG, map for infinite list

Tags: dictionary, erlang, infinite

I wanted to write a map for an infinite list.
This is, what I have so far:

```
-module(map).
-export([ints/0,take/2,map/2, double_int/1]).

ints() -> ints_from(0).

take(0, _)         -> [];
take(N, [H|LazyT]) -> [H | take(N-1, LazyT())].

double_int(N) -> 2 * N.

map(_, []) -> [];
map(F, [H | T]) -> [F(H) | map(F, T())].

ints_from(N) -> [N | fun () -> ints_from(N+1) end].
```

The problem is, that with the call

```
> L = map:ints().
[0|#Fun<map.0.104601022>]
> R = map:map(fun map:double_int/1, L).
```

I get a never ending process. I guess, the map is proceeding through the whole infinite list and therefore never ending.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the definition of `ints_from`?

Comment: ints_from(N) -> [N | fun () -> ints_from(N+1) end].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you represent lazy lists as lists whose tail is a function, your definition of `map` needs to return such a value as well:

```
map(_, []) -> [];
map(F, [H | T]) -> [F(H) | fun() -> map(F, T()) end].
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought returning a function on the list would be enough. But that is not the case. I understand infinite lists better now.